# TFS Feed Package direct URL

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to download Package from TFS Feed directly by URL?

**Why I need it**

I have maven artifacts in TFS Feed and I need to download one of them using curl during Docker image build.

**What I tried**

```
curl -v -o package.war -H "Authorization: Basic token..." "https://tfs.company.com/tfs/myCollectin/myProject/_packaging?feed=myFeed&package=com.company.application%3Apackage&version=1.0&protocolType=maven&_a=package#"
```

But it returns *401 Unauthorized* although I use the same token as for maven deploy.

Now I'm not sure if I have a bad URL or if I have a bad token or if it is possible at all.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering of my own question but I finally found the working solution:

`curl -o package.war -H "Authorization: Basic token..." "https://tfs.company.com/tfs/myCollection/_packaging/myFeed/maven/v1/com/company/application/package/1.0/package-1.0.war"`

Problem was in the URL itself. Correct URL pattern should be:

`https://tfs.company.com/tfs/myCollection/_packaging/myFeed/maven/v1/com/company/application/package/1.0/package-1.0.war`

... instead of:

`https://tfs.company.com/tfs/myCollectin/myProject/_packaging?feed=myFeed&package=com.company.application%3Apackage&version=1.0&protocolType=maven&_a=package`

If I looked right into the maven's deploy log, I would have figured it out earlier that the URL should be different and did not have to ask here. I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just try removing the double quotes `""` for the URL:

```
curl -v -o package.war -H "Authorization: Basic <token>" https://tfs.company.com/tfs/myCollectin/myProject/_packaging?feed=myFeed&package=com.company.application%3Apackage&version=1.0&protocolType=maven&_a=package#
```

Comment: With or without - it was still the same. Thanks for your try. Finally I realized that the problem was in the URL itself.